# Domain Driven Design efforts in dynamic languages?

Tags: domain-driven-design, dynamic-languages

Are you aware of any DDD efforts in a dynamic language ?

Practical resources on DDD tend to decrease quite dramatically when straying from enterprise-oriented solutions (a google search exluding C#, .NET, ASP and Java yields 10 times less results), but i couldn't actually find a single example of a DDD implementation in a dynamic language...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I'm not, but the principles remain the same so there shouldn't be any reasons why it wouldn't work out just as well, especially if the dynamic language in question has a good OO support (e.g. Ruby).

Even better perhaps, since your domain model could more easily make use of e.g. traits/mixins, and concepts from [DCI](http://www.artima.com/articles/dci_vision.html), etc. if there's a fit.

Comment: Interesting answer, I've been thinking the same, but my lack of experience with DDD prevailed on me to say so myself.
I'm still hoping for someone to come up with resources on specifics of DDD in dynamic languages though.

Answer (score 6):

Recently I tried to collect all known sources related to DDD in dynamic languages. I was end up with [this guthub repo](https://github.com/valentjedi/ddd-dynamic).

For reference here some code examples:

1) [Ruby DDD Sample App](https://github.com/paulrayner/ddd_sample_app_ruby)

2) [DDD in Django example](https://github.com/basco-johnkevin/ddd-python-django)

3) [Kanban board in Python with DDD approach](https://bitbucket.org/sixty-north/d5-kanban-python)

Answer (score 1):

There is some emerging frameworks like [Hanami-rb](http://hanamirb.org/) that encourage the use of DDD principles.

But as I've mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47558186/890890), although it is possible, there is a few downsides that may explain why the use of DDD is not so common in the "dynamic typed languages" word.

Answer (score 0):

The TYPO3 Association began working on the development of a PHP framework with a strong focus on encouraging Domain Driven Design some time ago. That framework is now part of the [Neos project](https://www.neos.io) and is called [Flow](https://flow.neos.io/).

The alpha version they presented back in 2008 (when I heard the last talk of the development head) looked already very promising. I haven't had a closer look so far though.

Our company has been doing PHP development with a DDD mindset for some time, however I didn't think about anything that would be specifically different for dynamic languages so far. I can only tell it works great for us.